# How to SINTER a Set and keys of a Hash in Redis?

Tags: redis

Let's say I have a Set and a Hash:

```
SADD a 1 2 3
HSET b 1 "value1" 2 "value2"
```

Now i want to get the intersection between the Set `a` and the keys of the Hash `b`. Is it possible to do in Redis?

The following doesn't work:

```
SINTER a b  # (error) WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, you can only achieve with Lua script:

```
eval 'local res = {}; for i, v in ipairs(redis.call("smembers", KEYS[1])) do if redis.call("hexists", KEYS[2], v) > 0 then res[#res + 1] = v end end return res' 2 set-key hash-key
```

A more compact solution is to use the `SORT` command. However, so far, `SORT` command doesn't support '*' as a glob style GET pattern for field name. I've created a [feature request](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/9617) for it.

Comment: When we call HEXISTS in this Lua script do we make a separate request across the internet for each value or is it done in one batch? If the former is right then I understand that this approach is not efficient for big Sets and Hashes, right?

Comment: The HEXISTS in Lua script is called on the server side, and there won't be multiple network round-trip time.